# i can't modify the css of integrated WordPress code

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a static web page which I use as my main homepage. I am designing the page with HTML and CSS code with some PHP code integrated from My WordPress.
The last integrated code is the code to display the recent 3 posts. It displays the posts, but I can't modify the result with CSS. Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php 
    $args=array('numberposts'=>3,'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );
    echo '<ul class="latest_posts">';
    foreach ($postslist as $post) :  setup_postdata($post);
?> 
<li>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?><br/>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title();?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I have tried everything in CSS, naming `div`, naming `span`, even using `ul` in CSS and nothing happens. It keeps it the same as it is.

Comment: which html tag  you want to modified??

Comment: the ul tag as it keep showing as vertical list with dots at the begining i want it to show as vertical without style and each post has box around it you can see the last result here [link](http://www.courseplanet.net)

Comment: attached your solution in answer try it on your style.css or custom.css you have. i hope your problem will solve with this.

Comment: This question is not useful until you provide the *rendered HTML* and the relevant CSS that is loading.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this on your custom css file

```
   ul.latest_posts{
    list-style: none !important;
    }
```

Comment: thank you it worked as a charm so if i need to make any other modification like making the list horizontal , should i add (important!) in every code

Comment: try with out !important first. if there is no rule already made by wordpress default  that will work for you without !important. If you overwrite by default rule made by wordpress or theme css you need to use !important ... and always make a custom css file. and put all your custom css when you need modifications. 
happy coding :)

Comment: when i deleted important it worked good , but now i can't inline the list , what tag do i need to call to inline the list

Comment: i can see the dots still on your live link .. any ways try 
 ul.latest_posts{  display: inline-flex;    list-style: none; }

Comment: maybe because i am running some website cashing script to speed up the website but it worked when i used another pc to open the site

Comment: yes worked , thank you man so if i need any other modification just add to ul.latest_posts tag

Comment: yes only if you need any modification there. Happy coding .

Comment: Dnt know who give the right answer as a vote down .. when the user  marked it as right .. maybe my bad luck..

Comment: yours is the right one and i marked it as the right answer

Answer (score 1):

`important` wouldn't be needed if your css rules are coded properly. The last rules should overwrite any previous ones. Make sure you're targeting the correct elements and put the rules you want to apply in the very end of your css code.

Comment: when i deleted important it worked good , but now i can't inline the list , what tag do i need to call to inline the list